# mysql password() in js

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I would like to generate the mysql-password hash from js.

I know the method with php functions,

```
$p = "example";
echo("$p<br>");
$p2= sha1($p,true);
echo("$p2<br>");   //ĂI')s~űvŠ-Ëo?
$result = sha1($p2);
echo("$result<br>"); //*57237bb49761f29ab9724ba084e811d70c12393d - this is the same as password("example") in mysql
```

and I'm trying to do this in javascript.

here is located the sha1 function:
http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha1.html

this is the hex2bin function I use to give the same result as sha1("",true);

```
function hex2bin(hex)
{
    var   bytes = [], str;

    for(var i=0; i< hex.length-1; i+=2)
        bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes);    
}
```

but at the last step it does not work. What can be the problem?

```
var p = "example";
console.log(p);
var p2 = hex2bin(hex_sha1(p));
console.log(p); //ÃI')s~ûv©-Ëo? - SEEMS OK
var result = hex_sha1(p2);
console.log(result); //9a5355dce26b1adfa0bdbe9f2b2a6e5ae58e5c9d WRONG
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it in javascript? If you know how to do it in php, why not request the result from a php file?

Comment: yes, because I want to submit password secure

Comment: Maybe you should start from the begin of what your trying to do. Generating a hashed password in javascript is not secure.

Comment: What do you do with the password once it's created?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I store it in the database

Comment: On the server? If your sending the password back to the server then the password is open to the public. You should send the password before encryption and hash it on the server before storing it in the db.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I will send not the password but the hash of it

Comment: That is my point. You shouldn't do that. If you don't know why read up on client-side to server security, after that if you still dont understand ask another question.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko your way:(client)--[passString]-->(server)--[hashOfpass]-->(db) dont you think this is more secure?:
(client)--[hashOfpass]-->(server)--[hashOfpass]-->(db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the example above, you are invoking: `hex_sha1(hex2bin(hex_sha1(string)))`. Are you sure that is correct? Why would you need `hex_sha1` twice?

Few month ago, I needed SHA1 in my JS and found this: http://phpjs.org/functions/sha1:512

... and it worked pretty ok ;)

### The solution (partly):

Well, as you suggested, the main problem was charset encoding. It seems that `MySQL` does not encode any data prior to hashing it. This does not represent problem when dealing it with hex data, however, `MySQL`'s `UNHEX`(`hex2bin` in JS) returns some unreadable chars and if we encode the result using `UTF8` that's where all breaks apart.

When I edited JS's SHA1 **not to encode data** to `UTF8` at line (I only commented the line):

```
str = this.utf8_encode(str);
```

everything seemed ok. However, as soon as I supplied some `UTF8` chars to input (such as Central European chars `čćžšđ`) it **started failing again**.

So, bottom line, if you disable `UTF8` in `JS`s `SHA1` function and do not supply `UTF8` chars on input it works fine.

I'm sure there is a solution to this such as `JS` function that will decode `UTF8` input so, JS could hash it properly.

Comment: because the mysql password hash is created that way. It uses for some reason sha1 algorithm twice.

Comment: I have tired your algorithm but it gives at the end 9a5355dce26b1adfa0bdbe9f2b2a6e5ae58e5c9d so hax2bin is wrong/ or some character encoding problem???

Comment: Well, I played a bit with `UNHEX` and your `hex2bin` functions and strangely enough when I supply constant argument they work the same. On the other hand when I supply `sha1` hashes (both the same) they output different value. I'll keep digging a little more and let you know if I find anything useful...

Comment: I gived up width this, and have chosen a more secure way: https. | I guess the base64_encode could solve this problem fully.

Answer (score 3):

Use http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#SHA-1 with 2 encodings.

Here is an example:

```
var password = "TestPassword";
var result = ("*"+CryptoJS.SHA1(CryptoJS.SHA1(password))).toUpperCase();
console.log("result : " + result);
```

Result will be *0F437A73F4E4014091B7360F60CF81271FB73180. If you check it with mysql password() it will be the same:

```
mysql> select password("TestPassword") as result;
+-------------------------------------------+
| result                                    |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *0F437A73F4E4014091B7360F60CF81271FB73180 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 2017**

Download file 2.5.3-crypto-sha1.js
https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads

```
var key = '*' + Crypto.SHA1(Crypto.util.hexToBytes(Crypto.SHA1('test'))).toUpperCase();

key = *94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29


Test in MySQL

SELECT PASSWORD('test') /* function */
UNION
SELECT '*94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29' /* Key generated by javascript */ 
UNION
select CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('test'))))); /* Logic for Password() function */
```